# Does color rendering index increase with brightness?

Tags: led, lighting

I've been reading about LED strips and thinking about switching to those from my serial incandescent lamp setup, and I can't figure out if CRI ([color rendering index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_rendering_index)) is tied to a certain standard brightness value (it has to be measured at some standard values, right?) or if no matter how dim or bright the light is, it will always be the same.

So, for example, if you take one strip section worth 2000 lumens and its CRI is 80%, will the CRI of the objects in a room increase if you use multiple of these strips?

I haven't had an opportunity to experiment with that and compare the stripes in a natural environment, so excuse me if the answer to that is very obvious.

Comment: AFAIK, the waveform of the color spectrum changes a bit with the forward current. So CRI shouldn't be constant through brightnesses with constant current dimming. However, with PWM dimming, you are always using the same current to achieve different brightnesses so maybe CRI would be more constant this way.

Comment: IMO, the CRI has to do with the crystal structure of the LED semiconductor. If some colours are missing from the spectrum I don't think they can magically appear if you turn on more LEDs at same time.

Comment: I don't mean dimming the stripe, but using more stripes to light up a room. I understand that dumming the LEDs themselves will change the light they give off, and I actually wanted to know more about that too, but that'd be a different question.

Answer (score 3):

CRI doesn't depend on brightness directly.

However, LEDs optimized for high CRI usually have lower lumen/W efficiency, and vice-versa. Very high lumen/W LEDs tend to be of the cool white variety, which doesn't have good color rendition. But high efficiency is great for flashlights.

I used CRI 95 LEDs for my kitchen lights and I'm very pleased with the result, it's much easier on the eyes than the weird tints produced by Low-CRI LEDs, although those would be OK for a corridor or a parking lot I guess.

---

EDIT (to complement Misunderstood's answer):

Color Rendition Index is about... color rendition. Color is the result of what the eye/sensor perceives. So, it is the product of three values:

- Spectrum of incident light
- Reflection spectrum of object
- Spectral sensitivity of eye/sensor.

If your light has a discontinuous/spiky spectrum (say, fluorescent or LED), and your object also has a ragged reflection spectrum, the resulting color will depend a lot on whether the peaks and valleys in both spectrums coincide. Results can be good, or completely off, depending on luck.

A white-looking "5600K daylight CCT" HMI lamp with a spectrum like this:

[image]

...will have TERRIBLE color rendition. If the object's reflected wavelengths peaks fall in between the light's peaks, color will be completely off.

Eyes and cameras are good at calibrating out color temperature shifts. People still look like people under skylight (which is outrageously blue like >7000K depending on time of day and other factors) or direct sunlight (slightly yellow) or a mix, or halogen (yellow), or an overcast day, etc.

HOWEVER, this calibration only works for full/smooth-spectrum lights. With spiky-spectrum lights, the missing wavelengths cannot be resurrected by color balance calibration. It will always look weird.

CCT is about the perceived color of the light itself. It is completely different and unrelated to CRI, which is about the color rendition of objects under said lights. For the same CCT, color rendition can be excellent or dismal depending on the actual light spectrum.

Here's a terrible CCFL light, officially 3200K:

[image]

Green and red stuff will look bad. A nice test for these kinds of lights is (if you're light skinned) to look at your wrist. With a full spectrum light, it looks OK. With these lights, the blue peaks will emphasize the big blue veins, and the skin takes a sickly color due to the lack of red.

Now, LEDs... If they use RGB or multiple mostly monochromatic LEDs, then the spectrum will be a collection of peaks, and CRI will suck. But you can adjust color temperature, which means you can have any coloration you want, as long as it's fugly! There's a sushi bar around here which uses RGB lights. I guess the owner must be colorblind, because it does truly evil things to the salmon sushis, they look like some kind of glow-in-the dark pink stuff straight out of Ghostbusters.

More bad lights:

[image]

Note that CRI is a flawed measurement which uses only few colors, and LEDs tend to score better than they actually look, because the standard CRI color samples miss the usual spectrum dip in the greens between the blue emitter peak and the phosphor. Also, high-CCT LEDs have a higher blue peak, and thus worse color rendition (but more lumens) than 2700K LEDs.

Until a more accurate normalized measurement is available, the best way to avoid bad colors from LEDs is to look at the spectrum and buy ones which minimize the blue peak and the green/cyan dip.

I would buy this one just by looking at the spectrum:

[image]

Now, on to the specialists:

http://www.cinematography.com/index.php?showtopic=52551&p=354505

Comment: I've noticed that most (if not all) 95+ CRI strips feature RGB diodes, at least in my local stores. Does yours have RGB or is it only a white?

Comment: Can you give a link for the RGB ones which shows an emission spectrum? Those are the ones I used: http://www.leds.de/en/LED-strips-modules-oxid-oxid-oxid-oxid-oxid/High-power-LED-strips/PowerBar-LED-Strip-12-Nichia-LEDs-CRI-90-warmwhite.html

Comment: Just found these, check the spectrum in the PDF, 2700K version is nice and smooth with very little blue spike https://store.yujiintl.com/collections/high-cri-led-module/products/bc-series-mod-cv

Comment: You may need google translate for this :P [This one for example](http://www.arlight.ru/catalog/svetodiodnye-lenty-100002/lenta-rt-2-5000-24v-warm3000-2x2-5060-600-led-cri98-021470.html), and [the range of 95+ strips of that particular manufacturer](http://www.arlight.ru/catalog-pro/svetodiodnye-lenty-100002/?filter_fit%5B%5D=T_20&filter_fit%5B%5D=T_45&filter_fit%5B%5D=T_8&filter_fit%5B%5D=T_75&filter_fit%5B%5D=T_44&filter_fit%5B%5D=T_46&filter_fit%5B%5D=T_48&filter_fit%5B%5D=T_52&filter_fit%5B%5D=T_63&fp_T_63%5B%5D=95..98&filter_fit%5B%5D=N_8&filter_fit%5B%5D=N_20&filter_fit%5B%5D=MY_45_1).

Comment: @user1306322 It says SMD 3528 LED, no RGB, no manufacturer data. Since it is an unknown brand LED, the CRI index may be faked as well. User peufeu linked white LED type NS6W183AT by Nichia, CRI 90.

Comment: I think (may be wrong) that RGD LEDs will create a spectrum with three spikes (R,G and B) and nothing in between. This should have very bad CRI...

Comment: @peufeu I think you have confused CRI with CCT.  What you said applies to CCT not CRI.

Comment: Nope, spiky discontinuous spectrums make weird colors and bad CRI, whereas smooth continuous spectrums (like sunlight or inansdescent) make high CRI... Contrary to what you say in your answer, CRI is not measured by looking at the color of the light (that's temperature) but by looking at the color of standardized color/pigment samples under the measured light. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_rendering_index#Test_method

Comment: Post edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

CRI is a measurement of the chromaticity as compared to the CIE standards.  It's purpose is to rate how closely the LED's color matches daylight or an incandescent light bulb.  This is important for example in a clothing store so the color of the clothing is correct.

Most white LEDs are actually deep blue, near UVA LEDs pushing a phosphor wavelength converter. Similar to how a UVA black light illuminates a black light poster.

The way to get the most lumens per watt is to increase the amount of green wavelengths as the eye perceives green to be brighter than any other color. Lumens are calculated using the CIE standards as well.

How well the white light matches various tungsten light bulb (e.g. 2700K-5600K) is called the CCT.

The higher CCT values usually have more green and less red so they tend to appear bluish.  Lower CCT have more red giving them a warmer color when the red mixes with blue.  The higher green is what increases the lumen calculations.

A 2000 lumen bulb will always be 2000 regardless of the CCT or CRI.

The lumens are calculated, using the CIE standard CIE Photopic Luminous Efficacy, from the measured radiant flux of each wavelength between 400 and 700nm.

I created the following image to show the CIE factor for some of the common wavelengths.  The measured Radiant values (milli-Watts) are multiplied by by the CIE factor when lumens are calculated.

[image: CIE Photopic Luminous Efficacy]